# Can someone help troubleshoot the cause of this error: ActiveRecord::Migration Error PG::WrongObjectType 'table' is not a view

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

I am having some issues with a migration on my rails application. When I execute the pending migrations I receive an error that looks like this:

```
PG::WrongObjectType: ERROR:  "contributions" is not a view
```

This is a snippet of the migration file:

```
class ReplaceContributionView < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def up
    execute <<-SQL
      CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW contributions AS (
      (
      SELECT id,
        id AS person_id,
        project_id AS project_id,
        name_fact_id AS name_fact_id,
        null AS position_id
      FROM people
      WHERE project_id IS NOT NULL

      .........etc etc. ...........
  end

  def down
   .........
  end
end
```

Checking my development database for the `contributions` table shows that it is indeed a view.

```
\d contributions

Materialized view "public.contributions"
Column    |  Type   | Modifiers
--------------+---------+-----------
 id           | bigint  |
 person_id    | bigint  |
 project_id   | integer |
 name_fact_id | integer |
 position_id  | integer |
Indexes:
    "index_contributions_on_id" UNIQUE, btree (id)
    "index_contributions_on_project_id" btree (project_id)
```

I also want to point out that migrating on my test database produces no error whatsoever and I am able to `migrate` and `rollback` without problems.

I'm stuck on this migration and can't do a thing until it resolves. What could be the problem? It clearly is a view unless `view` and `materialized view` are different things. Does anyone have any ideas? Help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Try dropping the view and then creating it instead of 'CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW':

```
def up
  execute('DROP VIEW contributions')
  execute('CREATE VIEW contributions AS (
    (
    SELECT id,
      id AS person_id,
      project_id AS project_id,
      name_fact_id AS name_fact_id,
      null AS position_id
    FROM people
    WHERE project_id IS NOT NULL

    .........etc etc. ...........'
end
```

Also, you may want to consider naming the table 'v_contributions' so that it is clear that table is a view table.